Tableau Calculation - Week Parameter & calculated field
I've been trying to display return on marketing investment ROMI for the CURRENT SELECTED WEEK (CW) in my table. I'm using a parameter that displays data by week number - all other calculated fields that I created in the same way worked.
Unfortunately I can't seem to find a solution on why the calculated field displays always the wrong number when selecting the week in my parameter. It seems to add up all available values from every day, not just the selected week from the parameter.
Any help or hints are greatly appreciated.

how many years of data  are stored in your datasource? using week as datepart, you may have the risk of getting the aggregated value for that week34 in multiple years

Not much at all. Only like 6 months worth of data. I'm starting to think my source table might be the issue since I already aggregated the data for financials by day while in my other source table I still have multiple entries per day. However there still should be a way to display each week aggregated, but I haven't found one yet.

actually your formula seems correct and I've double checked with a generic superstore. could you maybe add some more detail about the datasoucre? maybe a snippet of it?

can you add a screenshot of how your [SELECT WEEK] parameter is configured?
